# Как копировать содержимое текстового файла в таблицу excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

У меня есть батник (*.bat) в коде я запускаю батник, в корневом папке создается файл.txt со строками от двух до трех. Пытаюсь содержимое текст.тхт засунуть в переменную, а эту переменную записать в таблицу в excell, но выдает следующую ошибку:

> Цитата:
>   raceback (most recent call last): File "F:/Python_Projects/DateCollector 2/invert.py", line 86, in ws.append([username, pc_name, ip, phone, voip, dep, cur_data, laptop, laptop_sn, a]) File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 646, in append cell = Cell(self, row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=content) File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 113, in init self.value = value File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 216, in value self._bind_value(value) File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value)) ValueError: Cannot convert ['яюS\x00A\x00M\x00,\x00S\x003\x00C\x003\x005\x000\x00,\x00H\x00T\x00N\x000\x000\x008\x009\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00S\x00A\x00M\x00,\x00C\x007\x00H\x00G\x007\x00,\x00H\x00T\x00H\x00M\x005\x000\x000\x000\x001\x007\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00'] to Excel

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook      #excell module
import subprocess
filename = "1.xlsx"  #my excell with tabs
wb = load_workbook(filename) 
subprocess.check_call('monitor.bat', shell=True)  #running my *.bat and creating in root folder "note.txt" with two strings.
mon = open('note.txt')   #opening file.txt
monitors = mon.readline() #

ws.append([var1, var2 , monitors]) #try to put in tabs in excell
wb.save(filename) #save book
```

Прилагаю код.

Comment: Уточните немного вопрос. Не очень понятно, что за объект `ws`, вероятно это лист экселя. Но не понятно, где вы его открываете. проще всего это сделать `ws = wb['Имя листа']`.

Comment: Извиняюсь пропустил. Вы верно догадались это лист. `ws = wb.worksheets[0]` первый лист экселя. Но проблема не в этом, сам код работает, ошибка выходит когда пытаюсь добавить в ячейку объект `monitors`.

Comment: вообще для добавления текста в конкретную ячейке вам нужно нечто такое:
`ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = my_string`. Но если использовать именно append, то структура данных должны быть как [вот тут](http://zetcode.com/python/openpyxl/)

Comment: Если не сложно будет потом, опишите своё решение ответом на свой вопрос. Сам работаю с этой библиотекой - интересно)

Comment: пользуюсь append'ом что бы данные добавлялись в подледную свободную строку, а с индексом в ячейки так не получается (у меня не получается).  ` raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))` такую ошибку выдает. Что-то с конвертацией, но как решить, гугл не помогает)) или вопрос не могу сформировать

Comment: Я использую несколько кривую конструкцию для добавления в свободную строку, но мне она уже как привыклась:
`sheet['A' + str(row_num)].value`.
В данном случае добавляется, даже если данных в ячейке никогда не было

Comment: Спасибо за инфу, возьму на заметку)

Comment: В общем решил проблему: ```file = open('file.txt')
a = file.readline()
b = file.readline()
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not (line):
        break  ws.append ([var1, va2, a, b])``` Изначально команда не понимала как завести в одну ячейку сразу несколько строк. Этим кодом я назначил каждую строку в отдельные переменные

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('file.txt') 
a = file.readline() 
b = file.readline() 
while True: 
    line = file.readline() 
    if not (line): 
        break 
ws.append ([var1, va2, a, b])
```